# JQuery: Add HTML to Parent Div as Result of AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I can't quite figure out how to add HTML retrieved from an AJAX call to a PHP function.

First off, here is the AJAX function:

```
function selectListAJAX(fieldId, newclass){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://brand.emich.edu/forms-and-tools/sections/departmental/university-archives/monthly/ajax-selectbox.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { field_id: fieldId },
        success: function(response){
           $(newclass).html(response);
        },
        error: function(){
           alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

And here is the place where the HTML should be added:

```
$(this).parent().parent().after('
    <div class="form-group '+ field_name +'-row row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" name="'+ field_name +'[]" class="form-control item-field">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 selectajax">'+ 
            selectListAJAX(newFieldId, selectajax) +'
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 add-field">
            <input type="number" name="'+ field_name +'qty[]" class="form-control align-right ' + field_name + 'qty">
        </div>
    </div>
');
```

I've tried several variations of adding arguments to the function, etc., but the best I've been able to come up with is getting a big "undefined" placed within the div instead of the response.

Oh and bonus points if somebody can explain why I have to have the code within my .after() all smashed together for the browser to understand it. I've looked on previous threads and saw escaping lines with '\' but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: does `response` contains an xml string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that selectListAjax() doesn't return a value.  All processing of the resulting response should be within the success() handler of the ajax call, since ajax calls are (by definition) asynchronous.  Note that the method also likely returns before your success() handler completes.

Start small.

Try (html):

```
<div>
    <div class="target"></div>
</div>
```

(script):

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://brand.emich.edu/forms-and-tools/sections/departmental/university-archives/monthly/ajax-selectbox.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { field_id: fieldId },
        success: function(response){
           $('.target').html(response);
        },
        error: function(){
           alert("Error");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ah makes sense. Okay so this works but now the problem is that when I do this by class, each time I make a new select list this way it resets all other select lists. I can't really call by ID since everything is dynamically generated. And things like .closest() don't work because I have no selectors to add to that.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. I will put the solution in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

When your calling the selectListAJAX :

```
<div class="col-sm-3 selectajax">'+ 
   selectListAJAX(newFieldId, selectajax) +'
</div>
```

selectajax is a variable and you use it as a selector in the succes of the ajax. If you want to pass the selector it need to be in string like this :

```
<div class="col-sm-3 selectajax">'+ 
   selectListAJAX(newFieldId, + 'selectajax' +) +'
</div>
```

Comment: Good catch! Although this didn't turn out to be the ultimate issue.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Keith: "All processing of the resulting response should be within the success() handler..." This is correct. However, there also arises a problem where, when another select box is created, all existing select boxes are also re-created because I am asking jQuery to replace the HTML within **every** div with a class of "select" AJAX.

In order to add the list to **only the newly created div**, an ID must also be dynamically created for that div:

```
      success: function(response){
            var numberOfLists = $('.'+fieldName+'selectajax').length;

            $('.'+fieldName+'selectajax').each(function(index, element) {
                if(index == numberOfLists -1){
                    var idOfLast = $(this).attr('id', 'currentselectajax');
                    $(idOfLast).html(response);
                } else {
                    $(this).removeAttr('id');
                }
            });
     },
```

First, gather the length of the array (how many divs of the given class exist). Then, for each of those, find the last one (length-1). For that last one, create an ID for it and dump the response into it using .html(response). For all the others, remove the ID attribute so as to bypass changing the HTML within those divs.